# What happens inside the JVM so that a method invocation in Java becomes slower when you call it somewhere else in your code?

Tags: java, jvm, real-time, latency, jvm-hotspot

The short code below isolates the problem. Basically I'm timing the method `addToStorage`. I start by executing it one million times and I'm able to get its time down to around 723 nanoseconds. Then I do a short pause (*using a busy spinning method not to release the cpu core*) and time the method again N times, on a different code location. For my surprise I find that **the smaller the N the bigger is the `addToStorage` latency**.

For example:

```
If N = 1 then I get 3.6 micros
If N = 2 then I get 3.1 and 2.5 micros
if N = 5 then I get 3.7, 1.8, 1.7, 1.5 and 1.5 micros
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? I would like my method to consistently perform at the fastest time possible, no matter where I call it.

**Note:** I would not think it is thread related since I'm not using `Thread.sleep`. I've also tested using `taskset` to pin my thread to a cpu core with the same results.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JvmOdd {

    private final StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder(1024);
    private final List<String> storage = new ArrayList<String>(1024 * 1024);

    public void addToStorage() {

        sBuilder.setLength(0);

        sBuilder.append("Blah1: ").append(System.nanoTime()).append('\n');
        sBuilder.append("Blah2: ").append(System.nanoTime()).append('\n');
        sBuilder.append("Blah3: ").append(System.nanoTime()).append('\n');
        sBuilder.append("Blah4: ").append(System.nanoTime()).append('\n');
        sBuilder.append("Blah5: ").append(System.nanoTime()).append('\n');
        sBuilder.append("Blah6: ").append(System.nanoTime()).append('\n');
        sBuilder.append("Blah7: ").append(System.nanoTime()).append('\n');
        sBuilder.append("Blah8: ").append(System.nanoTime()).append('\n');
        sBuilder.append("Blah9: ").append(System.nanoTime()).append('\n');
        sBuilder.append("Blah10: ").append(System.nanoTime()).append('\n');

        storage.add(sBuilder.toString());
    }

    public static long mySleep(long t) {
        long x = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < t * 10000; i++) {
            x += System.currentTimeMillis() / System.nanoTime();
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int warmup = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int mod = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int passes = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        int sleep = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

        JvmOdd jo = new JvmOdd();

        // first warm up

        for(int i = 0; i < warmup; i++) {
            long time = System.nanoTime();
            jo.addToStorage();
            time = System.nanoTime() - time;
            if (i % mod == 0) System.out.println(time);
        }

        // now see how fast the method is:

        while(true) {

            System.out.println();

            // Thread.sleep(sleep);
            mySleep(sleep);

            long minTime = Long.MAX_VALUE;

            for(int i = 0; i < passes; i++) {
                long time = System.nanoTime();
                jo.addToStorage();
                time = System.nanoTime() - time;
                if (i > 0) System.out.print(',');
                System.out.print(time);
                minTime = Math.min(time, minTime);
            }
            System.out.println("\nMinTime: " + minTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Executing:

```
$ java -server -cp . JvmOdd 1000000 100000 1 5000
59103
820
727
772
734
767
730
726
840
736

3404
MinTime: 3404
```

Comment: I can only think of CPU cache misses, which doesn't happen in the JVM itself.

Comment: Good point @JornVernee! Isn't the difference too big for a CPU cache miss? Also, in the second or third call the CPU should have cached what it needs or no? How would we explore that hypothesis further?

Comment: The difference doesn't seem to big, memory fetches can take up to a 1000 ALU cycles. This really depends on what CPU you are running on, I don't know of any method to test it (maybe to dump the CPU cache before resuming, if that's possible is up to your CPU though, not Java).

Comment: Please, don't [cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info): http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/345768/1352 “Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network.”

Comment: @JörgWMittag I deleted the other one. Sorry about that.

Comment: You are mixing non-technical semantics into you analysis. There is no “pause” in your code. The thread is busy while executing `mySleep` and it’s only you who wants to see that as a sleep operation. Neither, naming the method `mySleep` nor heaving no real purpose, is relevant to the JVM. So, since there is no pause in the code, it also doesn’t “become slower after a pause”.

Comment: @Holger Agree! Initially I was using `Thread.sleep` that's why I called it a _pause_. Do you have a suggestion on how to better phrase it? I think it happens when a method is called in a different location of your code.

Comment: @JornVernee Do you know if it is possible to disable CPU caching? That would allow us to pinpoint it as the cause.

Comment: You just named it.

Comment: Note: Until the method has been called at least 10,000 times it might not have been compiled with the C2 compiler, so benchmarking it might not be very meaningful.

Comment: Have you had the jvm print out when it is optimising and pausing?   One smell with the warm up code is that one method has all of the loops in it including the non-warmup loops, that method may not be getting a chance to be optimised by hotspot as it is actively running.  If it does get optimised then it will be via an onstack replacement which does not perform the same as optimising a method that is not actively being run.  In other words, the odd performance could be coming from the test harness and not the method being tested.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm calling one million times in one site and few times in another site. Looks like Kirk nailed it down on his answer.

Comment: @LatencyFighter the place where you call it a few time should be slower as this code won't be optimised.

Answer (score 5):

There is so much going on in here that I don't know where to start. But lets start here....

```
           long time = System.nanoTime();
            jo.addToStorage();
            time = System.nanoTime() - time;
```

The latency of addToStoarge() cannot be measured using this technique. It simply runs for too quickly meaning you're likely below the resolution of the clock. Without running this, my guess is that your measures are dominated by clock edge counts. You'll need to bulk up the unit of work to get a measure with lower levels of noise in it.

As for what is happening? There are a number of call site optimizations the most important being inlining. Inlining would totally eliminate the call site but it's a path specific optimization. If you call the method from a different place, that would follow the slow path of performing a virtual method lookup followed by a jump to that code. So to see the benefits of inlining from a different path, that path would also have to be "warmed up".

I would strongly recommend that you look at both JMH (delivered with the JDK). There are facilities in there such as blackhole which will help with the effects of CPU clocks winding down. You might also want to evaluate the quality of the bench with the help of tools like JITWatch (Adopt OpenJDK project) which will take logs produced by the JIT and help you interrupt them.

Comment: By the way, there's a great discussion on the [mechanical sympathy google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mechanical-sympathy/E7keRLsVcyk/9pGXTySrDQAJ) about this very question.

Comment: A good discussion indeed.... I held the mistaken idea that the mySleep() method would not be jitt'ed away. In the past I was able to prevent dead code elimination by replacing void with a return value. However once mySleep() is inlined, the value dependency will disappear after which the inline'd mySleep() can be DCE'ed.

Answer (score 3):

There is so much to this subject, but the bottom line is that you can't write a simplistic benchmark like this and expect it to tell you anything useful. You will need to use JMH.

I suggest watching this: https://www.infoq.com/presentations/jmh about microbenchmarking and JMH

There's also a chapter on microbenchmarking & JMH in my book: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920042983.do

Answer (score 0):

Java internally uses JIT(Just in Compiler). Based on the number of times the same method executes it optimizes the instruction and perform better. For lesser values, the usage of method would be normal which may not fall under optimization that shows the execution time more. When the same method called more time, it uses JIT and executes in lesser time because of the optimized instruction for the same method execution.